# Card Header - link on icon stop collapse

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a card header in which I need to have an icon with an action on it when I click. The problem is when I click on it it will collapse my card which I don't want to do. Is there something I can do to prevent the collapse only on this icon?

The icon needs to be just beside the title as per client request and they absolutely want the full header to be able to collapse when click.

I think I will remove bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" and built my own collapse using .card-header:not(xxx) to prevent my link to stop in javascript.

```html
<h5 class="card-header">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#infoGeneral" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="infoGeneral" id="heading-info-general" class="d-block">
                    Information générale de la station <i class="far fa-comment"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-up float-right"></i>
                </a>
            </h5>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6vKj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take it out of the collapse element.

```html
<h5 class="card-header">
    <p class="d-block">Information générale de la station <i class="far fa-comment"></i></p>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#infoGeneral" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="infoGeneral" id="heading-info-general" class="d-block">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up float-right"></i>
    </a>
</h5>
```

Comment: Doing what You just put will remove the collapse on the entire header. I just need the icon <i class="far fa-comment"></i> to not collapse. I just added an image. The green section still need to perform the collapse.